# Whither is the "export to PDF" feature gone?

Tags: support, jobs, pdf

There used to be an export to PDF feature on Careers. I can't seem to find it anymore.

Where is it? Is it gone? If so, why? It was awesome! Can we get it back, please?

Comment: They moved the cheese, but it's still there.

Comment: *whither* - *"(archaic, formal, poetic or literary) To what place."*